# Magento 2 redirect non-www to www nginx and varnish

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx, varnish

what is the right way to redirect all http://domain traffic to https://www.domain
for magento 2 on nginx and varnish server?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/835887/redirect-http-to-https-using-varnish-4-1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about server configuration, not Magento-specific configuration

Answer (score -2):

Varnish is just caching and it doesn't affect the redirecting. To force www on Nginx check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486739/force-www-and-https-in-nginx-conf-ssl?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: varnish is able to do everything, you can even run it without any webserver in upstream...

Comment: so you're going to show us how you would recommend forcing www with varnish?

Comment: sure https://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRedirectInVCL